# run php program Skype

Tags: php, video, call, skype

I'd like to run Skype video chat whit access key, iv set these code:

```
<p><a href="skype: <?php echo $skipe; ?>?chat" accesskey="h">skipe</a></p>
```

the code set the Skype alias properly, when I press the access key, parameter are sent to Skype box, but this does not send the box of Skype on top, and does not trigger video calling (in skipe is crtl shift R)

how can I activate a video call

Comment: Don't you think there might be serious security implications with that?

Comment: bacause there are skype user in the code ?

Comment: @    Niet the Dark Absol   why there are skype user in the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let the user decide if one want to chat, call or whatever with
`<a href="skype:username?userinfo" >` or without paramters the default action.

If you want to start a video chat, use the the video option (append `&video=true` to the URL):
`skype:skype.test.user.1?call&video=true`

You can read more about the available options in the documentation :
http://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/reference#uriCallVideoExplicit

Comment: <p><a href="skype:<?php echo $skipe;?>?call&video=true" accesskey="h">skipe</a></p>